# Vue, reassigning and reusing response values for different objects

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I have a working vue function with an axios call but I need to define some of my response values differently and reuse them for an object without changing the overall structure. I currently have:

```
data () {
    return {
        dateEvents: [],
        events: [

        ],
},
created() {
    this.fetchItems();
},
methods: {
  fetchItems() {
   axios.get('/home/items')
    .then(response => {
      // handle success
      console.log(response.data)
      this.dateEvents = response.data
      this.events = response.data
    })
```

The problem is, I need to keep my current format for `dateEvents` but map these values to different names for the `events` object.

So right now my response.data is `item_id, item_title, item_available` which I still need for `dateEvents`. But for `events` I need to map it so that `events.title = item_title, events.start = item_available`

I tried this but it gives me undefined

```
axios.get('/home/items')
    .then(response => {
      // handle success
      console.log(response.data)
      this.dateEvents = response.data
      this.events.title = response.data.item_title
      this.events.start = response.data.item_available
    })
```

How can I keep the general structure but only change the assignments for my events object?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should map your `response.data` array to make new format array like this

```
this.events = response.data.map(({ item_title, item_available, ...item }) => ({
  ...item,
  title: item_title,
  start: item_available
}))
```

Comment: I think this works perfectly while I just leave my dateEvents as is. Thank yoU!